# How can I permanently disable the Mac keyboard backlight?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, keyboard

I'm running Lion, soon to upgrade to Mountain Lion once I can ensure compatibility with installed apps, on an MBPR, and in the meantime I'm being driven crazy by the keyboard backlight. Here's the deal: you may have heard about people who have issues with an undersensitive ambient light sensor, viz.: people turn on "automatically illuminate keyboard in low light" in System Prefs -> Keyboard, and then find that the light comes on too frequently.

They are helpfully informed to disable the automatic illumination, and manually to turn the light off using the <kbd>F5</kbd> and <kbd>F6</kbd> keys (actually, technically, the keyboard light down and keyboard light up keys when not using <kbd>fn</kbd> modifier).

Here's the funny thing: I have the "automatically illuminate" setting turned OFF, and I use the keyboard light keys to turn the keyboard light off.

Yet within a second, the light is back on.

Seriously!

Procedures to reproduce:

1. Be doing anything
2. Keyboard light is on
3. Press keyboard light dim button -- but whatever is reporting the keyboard illumination level thinks the keyboard light is already off:
   [image: Screenshot displaying keyboard illumination level of 0]
4. Press keyboard light *increase* button -- the light actually ends up dimmer, because it increases its illumination to one unit from what it thinks is 0 but is actually something higher.
5. Press keyboard light dim button again -- keyboard light switches off for a split second.
6. ???
7. No profit. The keyboard demons switched the light back on during step 6, and now the light is on again.

Once again: I have automatic illumination *DISABLED* [please don't make me upload another screenshot to prove it:) ].

Frankly, I don't need keyboard illumination. It's occasionally useful in pitch black, but I touch type anyway, so it is usually just an annoying distraction and waste of battery.

So, I'd like to just turn the darn thing off permanently. Terminal commands appreciated!

**Addendum:**
Apparently, the behavior does not repeat when plugged into power.

**Addendum 2:**
Apparently, the behavior does persist when plugged into power; it just takes longer for the computer to realize that it has stopped annoying me.

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't the answer you're looking for, but have you tried resetting the pram and smc? That might solve your problem without permanently killing the backlight

Comment: Actually, yes, but thanks. I assume (though I don't know a thing about this) that it doesn't make a difference to do so twice....

Comment: Depends... On older machines you seemed to have to reset pram several times to really clear it, I know that doesn't sound like it makes alot of sense, but most people observed the same.

Comment: Interesting. Maybe I will give that a shot sometime in the next few days.